# generating differently colored text in the same label in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to produce the following graph. This is what I have so far (please help make it nicer if you think there is a better way too)

But I really don't know how to color the label `lft=k-2*rgt\_dist` with different colors, nor to place the little man there. The arrows are also not fully correct.

Could you please help?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,10} { \node [draw, rectangle,fill=green!12, minimum width=1cm,minimum  height=1cm] (v\x) at (\x,0) {}; }
    \foreach \x in {1,3,7,8,10} { \node [draw,fill=red!32, minimum width=1cm,minimum  height=1cm] (v\x) at (\x,0) {}; }
    \node [draw,fill=yellow!32, minimum width=1cm,minimum  height=1cm] (v5) at (5,0) {};

    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,10} { \node [draw, rectangle,fill=green!32, minimum width=1cm,minimum  height=1cm] (u\x) at (\x,-3) {}; }
    \foreach \x in {2,3,...,8} { \node [draw,fill=green!82, minimum width=1cm,minimum  height=1cm] (u\x) at (\x,-3) {}; }
    \node [anchor=east](a) at (u0.west) {PreSum Fruits};
    \node [draw,fill=red!32,anchor=south west, yshift=3cm, xshift=0.3cm,minimum width=1cm,minimum  height=1cm,label={[label distance=0.3cm]right:Fruit}](t1) at (v10.north east){};
    \node [draw,fill=green!12,below=0.3cm of t1, minimum width=1cm,minimum  height=1cm,label={[label distance=0.3cm]right:No fruit}](t2){};
    \node [draw,fill=yellow!12,below=0.3cm of t2, minimum width=1cm,minimum  height=1cm,label={[label distance=0.3cm]right:StartPos}](t3){};

    \path [draw,densely dashed] ([yshift=-0.8cm]u2.center) coordinate (P1) -- ([yshift=3.5cm]v2.center);
    \coordinate (P2) at ([yshift=-0.8cm]u8.center);
    \path [draw,densely dashed] (P2) -- ([yshift=3.5cm]v8.center);
    \node [label={[red]below:L}] (label1) at (P1) {};
    \node [label={[red]below:R}] (label2) at (P2) {};
    \draw ([yshift=6cm]P1) to [edge node={node [above] {
                        lft=k-2*rgt\_dist }}] ([yshift=6cm]P2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a `matrix` with several `styles` and `lists`. The icon can be from `fontawesome5` but any other is also valid.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [
    font=\sffamily,
    cell/.style={minimum size=8mm, anchor=center, 
        rounded corners, draw=#1!50, fill=#1!15},
    cell/.default=black,
    fruit/.style={cell=red},
    startpos/.style={cell=orange},
    greensoft/.style={cell=green},
    fruits/.style={
        row 1 column #1/.style={%
            nodes={fruit}
        }
    },
    nofruits/.style={
        row 1 column #1/.style={%
            nodes={nofruit}
        }
    },
    starts/.style={
        row 1 column #1/.style={%
            nodes={startpos}
        }
    },
    presumsoft/.style={
        row 2 column #1/.style={%
            nodes={greensoft}
        }
    },
    presumhard/.style={
        row 2 column #1/.style={%
            nodes={greensoft, fill=green!35}
        }
    },
]
\matrix (A) [
    matrix of nodes, 
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={cell},
    row sep=5mm,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    fruits/.list={2,4,8,9,11},
    presumsoft/.list={1,2,10,11},
    presumhard/.list={3,...,9},
    starts/.list={6}
]
{&&&&&&&&&& \\  
 |[label=left:PreSum Fruits]|&&&&&&&&&& \\
};
\node[font=\Huge] at (A-1-6.north) {\faMale};
\draw[dashed] (A-2-3.south)++(0,-5mm) node[below] {L}--++(90:5cm) coordinate(aux1);
\draw[dashed] (A-2-9.south)++(0,-5mm) node[below] {R}--++(90:5cm) coordinate(aux2);
\draw[dashed, -Stealth, blue!70, ultra thick] ([yshift=-1cm]aux2) coordinate(aux)--(aux-|A-1-6.north) coordinate (auxman);
\draw[-Stealth, blue!70, ultra thick] ([yshift=-5mm]auxman)--([yshift=-5mm]aux);

\draw[dashed, -Stealth, green!70, ultra thick] (auxman) -- (auxman-|aux1);
\node[above=3mm of auxman] {\textcolor{green}{lft\_dist}\textcolor{black}{=k-}\textcolor{blue!70}{2*rgt\_dist}};
\node[startpos, above right=1cm and 0pt of A.north east, label=east:StartPos] (ST) {};
\node[cell, above=1mm of ST, label=east:No Fruit] (NF) {};
\node[fruit, above=1mm of NF, label=east:Fruit] (F) {};
 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Only one little part of the work needed to make all modifications requested.
To make text in color change the corresponding line of the code this way:

```
\draw[latex-,green] ([yshift=6cm]P1) to [edge node={node [above] {
                \textcolor{green}{lft}\textcolor{black}{=k-}\textcolor{violet}{2*rgt\_dist }}}] ([yshift=6cm]P2);
```

Comment: Do you also happen to know how to generate the person icon? Thanks a lot.

Comment: also upvoted, thanks a lot.